# How to Recover Text in a Picker (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, controls, picker

I am developing an App in Xamarin in which I have a Picker that I declare in an XML in this way:

```
 <Picker x: Name = "motivePicker"
                        Title = "Select a Reason"> </ Picker>
```

Then on my page .CS I set it this way:

```
        motivoPicker.Items.Add ("Bad Parking");
        motivoPicker.Items.Add ("No Driver's License");
        motivoPicker.Items.Add ("No Reflective Vest");
```

But at the time of retrieving the data that I selected my user, I do not have success .... I am occupying the following form:

```
 MotivoLocalID = [motivoPicker.SelectedIndex]. MotivoLocalID
```

Any help for me?

Comment: That syntax is ObjectiveC?? is not C# for sure...

Comment: Its CSharp @Gusman

Comment: Paste the line `MotivoLocalID = [motivoPicker.SelectedIndex]. MotivoLocalID` on the code and try to compile, tell me then if that's valid C# syntax...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a list of items from your code so you have nothing to refer to when the item is selected in the picker. You need to do something like this:

```
public class MotivoItem
{
    public int MotivoLocalId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

var motivoItems = new List<MotivoItem>();
motivoItems.Add(new MotivoItem {MitivoLocalId = 1, Description = "Bad Parking" });
motivoItems.Add(new MotivoItem { MitivoLocalId = 2, Description = "No Driver's License" });
motivoItems.Add(new MotivoItem { MitivoLocalId = 3, Description = "No Reflective Vest" });

foreach (var motivoItem in motivoItems)
{
    motivoPicker.Items.Add(motivoItem.Description);
}
```

Then when the item is selected you can refer to the list via the selected item index:

```
var MotivoLocalID = motivoItems[motivoPicker.SelectedIndex].MotivoLocalID;
```

Comment: I run an object called InfracionLocal in this way:

  Var infraccionLocal = new Local Infraccion
            {
                // InfraccionID = IDInfraccion,
                MotifLocalID = MotivoItems [motifPicker.SelectedIndex]. MotivoLocalID,
  };